# Base Level User Input that writes code into the program?

Tags: java, netbeans, user-input

I'm a student in an entry level computer programming course. We are using java through NetBeans. We are working on our final projects and are allowed to use internet resources.

I'm wondering if anyone can assist me in creating a user ability to code directly into my program through a string.

Basically, if their string input isn't recognized by any of my 'if' statements, the program will prompt them to write their own reply to their question. I wish my program to allow them to directly code a reply. By reply I mean a string will appear (I'm writing an AI conversation bot which reply to their questions). I'm prepared to write the code where their "written response" fills in a section and I write the rest.

How do I write code into the program with user input in it?
Example, I don't know if it works:

```
if (String.equalsIgnoreCase"hello") {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hi");
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sorry your message wasn't recognized. Create a reply for this message for the future.")
    //Then Somehow let the user create their own reply into the code
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I'm sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: Your post is extrremely confusing and there's no question in it. What is it that you're trying to do and what is the actual problem? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @xxbbcc Im sorry. I tried to edit and clear things up a bit.